# Can any YouTube channel restrict to don't allow to play videos in YoutubePlayerView in Android?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, ytplayerview

I am making an Android app for YouTube with YouTube API. I just retrieved JSON and parsed into List, data parsed and displayed in list successfully. But when I pass data to `YoutubePlayerView` to play video, it was blocked. So is there any way to resolve this or any alternative method?

Screenshot.
[image]

Comment: yas they can disable playback, i have same problem i solve it like this https://github.com/ameerhamza6733/ameerhamza6733.championtrophy2017schedule/blob/025f9bdb327e662d7a6aa80635906e257dd45db8/app/src/main/java/ameerhamza6733/championtrophy2017schedule/activitys/YoutubePlayer.java#L315

Comment: @AmeerHamza thanks for Replying , can your please tell me what will this do , should it open in webVIew ?

Comment: yas, you have no other option left